# Find duplicate records in table by more than one criteria

Tags: php, mysql

```
+-------------------------+
| SKU  |  UPC  |   NAME   | INVID
+-------------------------+
| 001  |  111  |   NAME1  |  1
| 001  |  null |   NAME2  |  2
| 0-1  |  111  |   NAME3  |  3
| -01  |  111  |   NAME4  |  4
| 002  |  222  |   NAME5  |  5
| 002  |  null |   NAME6  |  6
| 003  |  333  |   NAME7  |  7
+-------------------------+
```

I want to find duplicate records in this table by two criterias. First is SKU, second is UPC. At this case duplicate records are [1,2,3,4] and [5,6]. 
Rows [1,2] are duplicate because sku numbers are matched. Rows [1,3,4] are duplicates  because UPC numbers are matched.
The first duplicate group should look like this:

**GROUP1***

```
+-------------------------+
| 001  |  111  |   NAME1  |  1
| 001  |  null |   NAME2  |  2
| 0-1  |  111  |   NAME3  |  3
| -01  |  111  |   NAME4  |  4
+-------------------------+
```

The second duplicate group should look like this:

**GROUP2***

```
+-------------------------+
| 002  |  222  |   NAME5  |  5
| 002  |  null |   NAME6  |  6
+-------------------------+
```

How can I found this groups with mysql query ?
If I found duplicates records I set a grouID***** of any duplicate record in table.

I tried this, but not show all duplicates.

```
select sku, upc
from inv
WHERE sku is not null 
GROUP BY sku, upc HAVING count(sku)  > 1 OR count(upc)  > 1
```

This is SQL schema:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d760/2

This query return empty result.

Comment: That sql fiddle site is brilliant for SQL questions, thanks for introducing it

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 queries that do what you want and return the same columns you can use a UNION to make them appear as one result set.

This may include duplicate-duplicates though (records that appear in both duplicate queries)

Edit: Or use subqueries

```
select * from inv where upc in (select upc from inv group by upc having count(upc) > 1) 
union
select * from inv where sku in (select sku from inv group by sku having count(sku) > 1);
```

(I've got to get back to work now, but hopefully this will set you on road to solution)

Comment: select sku, upc, count(sku)
from inv
WHERE sku is not null 
GROUP BY sku HAVING  count(sku)  > 1
UNION 
select sku, upc, count(upc)
from inv
WHERE sku is not null 
GROUP BY upc HAVING  count(upc)  > 1 and this not return correctly result

Comment: This isn't an exact match (sorry, got to go) but it may help: `select * from inv where upc in (select upc from inv group by upc having count(upc) > 1) 
union
select * from inv where sku in (select sku from inv group by sku having count(sku) > 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that show duplicated entries as a single result:

```
select distinct i1.*
  from inv i1, inv i2
  WHERE i1.sku is not null AND 
    (i1.sku = i2.sku OR i1.upc = i2.upc) AND i1.idinv != i2.idinv
  ORDER BY idinv
```

this is realized joining the table with itself and looking for distinct matching.